# Plaid - Investments and Transactions together

Tags: plaid

I need to display transaction bank and investment bank in mobile app.
following the plaid document .

https://plaid.com/docs/investments/add-to-app/#create-a-link_token
https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/add-to-app/#create-a-link_token

I created my link token

```
https://{{env_url}}/link/token/create

{
    "client_id": "***",
    "secret": "******",
  "client_name": "Insert Client name here",
  "country_codes": ["US"],
  "language": "en",
  "user": {
    "client_user_id": "test"
  },
  "products": ["transactions","auth"]
}
```

but my investment bank details are not listing. only other banks are listing.

then I tried   `"products": ["transactions"]` only
then transaction and investment bank are listing.
but when I tried to use the api using investment bank access token then i am getting like this

https://{{env_url}}/investments/transactions/get

I am getting 400 and

```
{
    "display_message": null,
    "documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#invalid-input-errors",
    "error_code": "INVALID_PRODUCT",
    "error_message": "client is not authorized to access the following products: [\"investments\"]",
    "error_type": "INVALID_INPUT",
    "request_id": "JywR16ucSyFYXGF",
    "suggested_action": null
}
```

if I use the access-token of investment bank for fetching `/transactions/get` transaction  also null.

then I tried   `"products": ["transactions","investments"]` only,
then again I am not getting displaying the investments banks.

I am totally confused here. I want to display all investment bank and normal banks at a time. and need to display the investment transaction and normal transaction..

[image: investment bank]

[image: institutions]
[image: bank]

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display all investment bank and normal banks at a time.

Currently there is no way to do this in Link. Link will only show banks that support ALL the products you initialize it with. What you can do is in your UI give users a choice whether they want to link a "normal" bank or a brokerage and then initialize Link with either transactions or investments depending on which one they pick.

> when I tried to use the api using investment bank access token then i am getting like this

It sounds like you might be using Development as your environment instead of Sandbox? Developers can now use Investments in Development by default, but this is a very recent change. If you created your Plaid account more than 5 days ago, the fix will not apply to you. Instead, you can either file a support ticket requesting Investments in Development, or you can use Sandbox.

> if I use the access-token of investment bank for fetching /transactions/get transaction also null.

That's expected, you need to use the Investments endpoints for getting Investments transactions.

Comment: ok.. But I found that in status money app. every bank is displaying. I am attaching the video

Comment: I can't see the video, but I tried out Status Money and the bank account linking flow that I was able to see did not use Plaid.

Comment: I am attaching the screenshot that connecting bank

Comment: "products": ["transactions","investments"] is added while creating link token, but not getting both application

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshots! They are not screenshots of a Plaid flow; Status Money is not using Plaid in that UI.